# How to click button using JSOUP?

Tags: android, button, click, jsoup

I have a a problem here

I have a website which I must parse, but here's button

```
<a class="iceCmdLnk" href="javascript:;" id="mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144"
onblur="setFocus(&#39;&#39;);" 
onclick="var 
form=formOf(this);
form[&#39;mainform:_idcl&#39;].value=&#39;mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144&#39;;
return iceSubmitPartial(form,this,event);"
onfocus="setFocus(this.id);">
<span class="iceOutTxt" id="mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id145" title="Select  &quot;My Tasks (0)&quot;">My Tasks (0)
</span>
</a>
```

This button makes site to open table, and this table is most interesting for me 
Please help me to click it using JSOUP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSoup is not a browser. It will not interpret and execute JavaScript. Therefore your approach will not work. However, you could analyse the network traffic of that AJAX call taht dynamically fills the table in question and mimic these requests directly. Or you could use tools like [selenium webdriver for android](http://selendroid.io/) to access the page within a real browser.

Comment: Can I use webview to click it?

Comment: You may be able to inject a JavaScript that clicks on the button inside a webview. I am no real expert in this though.